# meaning of Rage Kiddies

Tags: vocabulary

the excerpt below is about life becoming cheap after people began to be cloned because thanks to cloning, people go on living in their new bodies after they die. Can you tell me what is meant by Rage Kiddies? I couldn't find any cultural references to it on the internet.Thanks in advance.

" 'Life became so cheap, when we got cloning' Joanna said. "Euthanize yourself and just skip over terminal illness. **Rage Kiddies** inventing impossible sports, taking massive risks with their lives because who cares?"

source: Six Wakes by Mur Lafferty

Comment: This sounds like a part of the built-world of the story you’re reading. That is, it’s a subculture invented by the author to add color and life to his world. I don’t think it exists outside the book. If the book further mentions them, you can learn more about who they are; if it doesn’t, you don’t have to worry about them much.

Comment: As this question deals with a term coined for a fictional world within one particular author's work, and not a term in general use outside that world and that work, I question it being on topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because --- see comment above.

Comment: poetic license ...

Comment: "Kiddies" is often used to refer to a group of (generally young) adults who obsess over some concept or activity.  And I would take "rage" to obliquely reference the concept of "rage" parties in "alternative" culture, where activities are performed to excess.

Answer (score 1):

Since the K in "kiddies" is capitalized, it's a proper noun.  There is some group or organization or entity named "Rage Kiddies" in the story.  This is underpinned by the fact that the book in German doesn't translate the words "Rage Kiddies" into German but leaves them in English, meaning that is a proper name within the mythos of the story.

> »Ein Leben ist so billig geworden«, sagte Joanna.
>
> »Man euthanasiert sich selbst und überspringt einfach eine schlimme
>   Krankheit. Die Rage Kiddies...
>
> -[Das sechste Erwachen](https://books.google.com/books?id=txk-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT79&dq=%22Rage%20Kiddies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi54d6P8JbcAhUC9IMKHajDDl8Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Rage%20Kiddies%22&f=false) (The Six Wakes)

Based on that, it's impossible to say what "Rage Kiddies" is exactly supposed to mean, but here's what we know:

- "[Rage](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rager)" is a term that traditionally means "anger," but in the vernacular, it means "party," like a "rager" is an extremely wild party.
- "[Kiddies](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kiddie?s=ts)" is a diminutive form of "kids."

Therefore, in the context of a story about people who essentially have eternal life because of cloning providing them with an endless supply of new bodies, I would imagine that Rage Kiddies is a term for a group of people who never grow old because they party so hard that they destroy the body they're in before it has a chance to get old and so then always have a new, young body to keep on partying hard in.